# Reading from Chrome History with Open Chrome Browser

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am trying to read rows from the `urls` table in Chrome's `History` database **with Chrome running**.  I only want to read from the database, not write.  Is this possible?  Here is my code below to access the table:

```
import os
import sqlite3

user = os.getlogin()
chrome_history_database = f"C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History"

query = "SELECT * FROM urls Limit 10"
conn = sqlite3.connect(chrome_history_database)
for row in conn.cursor().execute(query).fetchall():
  print(row)
conn.close()
```